# How to link CSS file from css folder in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am totally newbie for the wordpress theme development. I am trying to add style.css file which laid in CSS folder of my root folder. How can I add it? Please hurry up, I want my answer at this time if possible.

Comment: In your root root folder ? or the root folder of the template?

Comment: root folder of my theme

Comment: Hey Fralec if you have the answer then plz help me

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: "Please hurry up..." ?!? Read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: ok thanks Fralec and Markratledge both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-awesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0' );
```

Put that in your `functions.php` file:

```
...
function style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-awesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action('setup-style', 'style');
....
```

See [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );` for root `style.css`

Comment: Thanks Anish for your answer